# Python Scheduler for conditional scheduling

Tags: python, mongodb, algorithm, api, scheduler

Can someone help me write a python scheduler which does jobs ( for example, fetches data from an API / Database) according to certain conditions like based on number of retries of calling this API and priority wise sorting etc.?

Answer (score 0):

I'm a beginner with Python, but the [schedule package](https://pypi.org/project/schedule/) is pretty straight forward. Using `pip install schedule` simply define a function for your job and set the schedule. Your code may look something like:

```
import requests
import schedule

def job(url, filename=''):
   with requests.get(url) as req:
       with open(filename, 'wb') as f:
            for chunk in req.iter_content(chunk_size=1024000):
                if chunk:
                    f.write(chunk)
job(url)
schedule.every().hour.do(job, url=url)
while True:
       schedule.run_pending()
       time.sleep(1)
```

Answer (score 0):

[Rocketry](https://rocketry.readthedocs.io/) is a condition-based scheduler and you can make own conditions easily:

```
from rocketry import Rocketry
from rocketry import daily

app = Rocketry()

@app.cond()
def has_data():
    ... # Should return True or False
    return True

@app.task(daily & has_data)
def do_thing():
    ... # Run the task


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run()
```

It also supports cron-like scheduling, task pipelining etc.

The library is found from Pip:

```
pip install rocketry
```

Relevant links:

- [Documentation](https://rocketry.readthedocs.io/)
- [Source code](https://github.com/Miksus/rocketry)